# Итерация по парам соседних символов строки

Tags: rust

Имеется строка `s` чётной длины. Как можно написать цикл, итерирующийся по непересекающимся парам соседних символов, то есть:

- (`s[0]`, `s[1]`)
- (`s[2]`, `s[3]`)
- ...

---

Сейчас [имеется такое решение](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=953be799d159338dfd784d7d3f936dc4), но кажется оно далеко от оптимального

```
let s = "abcdef";
let v = s.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
for pair in v.chunks(2) {
    let (a, b) = (pair[0], pair[1]);
    println!("{} {}", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Если можно подтаскивать крейты, то проще всего итертулзы взять будет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51268450/2870802

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно